# I'm trying to create a bootable ubuntu stick but Rufus keeps repeating the same section again and again

Tags: boot, usb

I've followed the process of downloading required files and have been trying for hours to complete this process bur Rufus just keeps looping .  Whenever I get to the end of copying the iso files it just repeats.

Update
I have realised that I misinterpreted the instructions about the end of the process.  I should have pressed close instead of Start.  Having done this I have a drive named Ubuntu but it only has 1 mb used on it.  I think I must have something corrupted.  Perhaps I should simply delete everything and go back to square one

Comment: 'amd64' refers to 64-bit PC architecture, which includes the Intel i5. It's correct for i5, and not an error.

Comment: Would see if another burning program works if Rufus is being difficult.  Can also try another USB stick, if one is handy.

Comment: Rufus has a good reputation. Have you checked with md5sum, that the iso file was downloaded correctly. Rufus can calculate the md5sum for you, and you can check with the listed value from where you downloaded the iso file. -- It is also possible that your USB stick is damaged. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035).

Comment: I recommend using etcher -- it's also open-source.  It's not as feature-rich as rufus, but it's also practically impossible to encounter user error because you have only two options: source ISO and destination.

Comment: Depends on what you are using the USB for. If only using to install Ubuntu balenaEtcher is a good choice. If you want to try Ubuntu and save settings, data and installed programs, stick with Rufus or better yet mkusb,.

Comment: Thank you for all the advice.  Part of the problem here is that I lack expertise.  I'm not technically savvy enough to properly understand the verification process.  I'm thinking of binning my initial download of the ubuntu iso and starting again.